# jQuery doesn't work in a view of my mvc website

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages

in a page of my asp.net mvc website jquery not worked.

when i test the html source then i see the jquery script is not written

but i used only one  master page to load all  jquery on every page .

so where my jquery. when i debug my jquery then error found $ is not defined
off course it come because jquery not load

are you know why my master page's jquery not come to my page even if  i use same master page for all views of my website.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
        google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.0");
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
  // Some other code here
        });
    </script>
```

when i check this jquery not found. i not know why but i am sure that i use same master page on all views [because i am only build a master page for it].

the problem is jquery not load to page but i don't know why he not load in my page

Comment: You're going to need to post some source code. We have no idea how to fix your problem if you don't post any code for us to look at.

Comment: i've tested your code, there's no problem at my end, do you have interenet connection when you tested that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this piece of code to intialize

$(document).ready(function() {
      initialize();
});

Answer (score 0):

your code should be working

try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see any javascript errors and debugging

you can also host your own copy of jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the OnLoad callback for the JSAPIs from google.

```
function initialize() {
    $(function () {
        // Some other code here
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Otherwise the jquery script hasn't loaded when the document ready function is evaluated.